# How do I know what certificate should I use for a request?

Tags: node.js, ssl, axios

If I just paste this link on a browser https://apis.satcompany.com.br/partners I get a response saying I need a token, but if I do it on axios, it throws a `AxiosError: unable to verify the first certificate`

The solution seems to load the certificate like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import https from 'https'

const headers = {};

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem'),
})

const data = await axios.get(url, { httpsAgent, headers })
```

But how do I find those files? Where does the browser look for them?